# Call new block in template with event and observer magento 1.9.x

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer

I need to create a new block in the sucess page when a customer wins a gift (all 10 commands) how do I do that? Can you help me please

This is my observer

```
public function countOrder(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {

$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$writeConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');

$action = $observer->getEvent()->getAction();

$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId());
$_orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('customer_id',$order->getCustomerId())
         ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from'=>strtotime('-20 day', time()), 'to'=>time(),'datetime' => true));                
$_orderCnt = $_orders->count();

Mage::log( $_orderCnt, null, 'count.log');    


  if( $_orderCnt % 10 === 0 ) {


          Mage::log( $_orderCnt . ' ', null, 'win.log'); 

        // i want add new block or create a new template success for the winner !!! 

  }  
}
```

this is my config.xml

```
 <events>
        <checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
            <observers>
                <mycustom_module>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>mycustom_module/observer</class>
                    <method>countOrder</method>
                </mycustom_module>
            </observers>
        </checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
        <core_block_abstract_to_html_before>
            <observers>
                <mycustom_module>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>mycustom_module/observer</class>
                    <method>insertBlock</method>
                </mycustom_module>
            </observers>
        </core_block_abstract_to_html_before>
    </events>
```

How i can add new block or create a new template success for the winner ? i don't understand how i can do this ? Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this:

```
$layout = Mage::app()->getLayout();
$block = $layout->createBlock('core/template', 'payment_custom_block');
$block->setTemplate('custom_message.phtml');
$layout->getBlock('footer')->append($block);
```

Comment: Thank you Prince, so i create new template in design/frontend/default/default/template/Myfolder/custom_message.phtml. In my function countOrder in my observer in my condition for the winner (if( $_orderCnt % 10 === 0 )) . I have put your code but it's not work , it's in success page than i want to add a message or picture for the winner .